Should we decide on a general formatting style for references?
There are already a couple of great suggestions on how you should reference articles. These have been summarized by Ben in one all encompassing answer.
From this another question arose how to properly format these references, particularly how to format the reference list at then end of an answer.
I suggest the following approach:

Up/down vote this question in order to reflect your opinion on whether we need a formatting style.
Post suggested formatting styles as an answer, using the actual content of the following answer, applying the formatting of your preference.
Up/down vote the answers which represent the formatting you like.


From wikipedia:
Maslow's hierarchy of needs is a theory in psychology, proposed by Abraham Maslow in his 1943 paper A Theory of Human Motivation. [ 2]
Neher (1991, FREE PDF) summarises and critically evaluates the theory.
  From the abstract:
This critique of Maslow's theory of motivation examines all of its
  major components. The theory is summarized and its basic propositions
  are analyzed in the light of internal logic, other relevant theories,
  and related research. This examination points up many deficiencies in
  Maslow's theory, which enjoys wide acceptance, especially among
  humanistic psychologists. Suggestions are made regarding modifications
  to the theory that would remedy many of its more serious problems but
  at the same time preserve its perceptive insights.
The lack of empirical evidence was already discussed in an older article by Wahba et al. (1976).
The uncritical acceptance of Maslow's need hierarchy theory despite
  the lack of empirical evidence is discussed and the need for a review
  of recent empirical evidence is emphasized. A review of ten
  factor-analytic and three ranking studies testing Maslow's theory
  showed only partial support for the concept of need hierarchy. A large
  number of cross-sectional studies showed no clear evidence for
  Maslow's deprivation/domination proposition except with regard to
  self-actualization. Longitudinal studies testing Maslow's
  gratification/activation proposition showed no support, and the
  limited support received from cross-sectional studies is questionable
  due to numerous measurement problems. The difficulties with testing
  the theory are discussed and the conceptual, methodological, and
  measurement problems of the studies reviewed are detailed. The
  implications of the findings and future directions for research are
  outlined.
References
Neher, A. (1991). Maslow's theory of motivation: A
  critique. Journal of Humanistic Psycholgoy, 31, 3. FREE PDF
Mahmoud A. Wahba, Lawrence G. Bridwell, Maslow reconsidered: A review of research on the need hierarchy theory (1976), or a free pdf scan here

The content of this example answer was shamelessly copied from two answers to a real CogSci question.

we should ask people to format references clearly (I suspect most will use something resembling APA because they are familiar with it), but having an official policy will cause needless editing of decent questions and answers.

@ArtemKaznatcheev I think for a site attempting to court academics (and in general) it makes much more sense to specify and maintain a specific structure for references (which will be in the majority of answers)

@BenBrocka cstheory has successfully courted academics and it does not enforce a citation style. I don't think academics care all that much about a consistent citation style (I know I don't) but they care about the quality of questions and answers.

Also, it's currently framed as an encouraged style; if anyone is willing to take the time  to edit other people's questions or answers to improve the referencing, that sounds great to me. If people don't provide thorough references, the answer can still be good.

Another way to move forward on this is to also discuss particular issues related to referencing and then absorb these decisions into Ben's overall answer.

@JeromyAnglim: I agree we should first wait a while until we have reached a consensus (as far is possible on meta) on Ben's answer before starting to edit answers to reflect this post. This question is meant solely to address the formatting issues.

Furthermore, because we establish a preferred style, doesn't mean you are supposed to go through our history of posts and start editing all of them. We inherit standard editing guidelines from the SE network. I'll clarify this in this question and start a new post related to editing guidelines specific to our site.

The issue of style for the references section has come up. I still find the <sub> subscript method to be superior to the blockquote or References header as it deemphasizes the reference section rather than emphasizing it. The reference section should be easy to locate and read but should not catch the eye like bold and blockquotes do.
References
 Neher, A. (1991). Maslow's theory of motivation: A critique. Journal of Humanistic Psycholgoy, 31, 3. FREE PDF
Mahmoud A. Wahba, Lawrence G. Bridwell, Maslow reconsidered: A review of research on the need hierarchy theory (1976), or a free pdf scan here
Best I can tell, blockquote was preferred because someone thought each reference would have to be wrapped in <sub> tags but this is not the case; as you can see from the source of this post, only one set of tags is needed, but lines need to be broken by two spaces and a return at the end of a line, not two returns.

" someone thought each reference would have to be wrapped in  tags" ... that would have been me. :) Thanks for pointing out a way around this.

As I mentioned in chat though, I'm not sure why the double return paragraph break messes this up, I'm not sure it should.

I asked about it on meta.

This meta answer makes it clear this is by design.
